# NetBeans cannot find my file

Tags: netbeans, filepath

I have to specify a filepath. I get a FileNotFoundException, but I don't know what's wrong with my filepath.

Here it is. It's specified in a bundle.properties file:

```
org_netbeans_modules_autoupdate_silentupdate_update_center=file:/Users/Jesper/Desktop/netbeans_site/updates.xml"
```

Exception:

```
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.autoupdate.updateprovider.DownloadListener]: Reading URL file:C:/Users/Jesper/Desktop/netbeans_site/updates.xml" failed (java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Jesper\Desktop\netbeans_site\updates.xml" (Syntaksen i filnavnet, mappen eller diskenhedsnavnet er forkert))
```

Translation of the last part: "Syntax in filename, folder or diskunitname is wrong".

The file I need it to find is called "updates.xml" and is located on my desktop in a folder called "netbeans_site".

Comment: Please post the whole  block of code that makes the call to the file

Comment: @Dazak  It's not actually called by a piece of code, it's just a filepath that's specified in a bundle.properties file.

Comment: I suppose that could be: or the quotation marks, or.. Maybe netbeans is taking the path relative, try putting the whole path (like c:/users/jesper/desktop... Etc)

Comment: @Dazak Not sure why i didn't even notice that quotation mark... It was the cause of the problem. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome, I put the answer in order to close the question ;) I will appreciate that mark it as correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like I post in the comments... The problem is the quotation marks in the path